# Kotlin: Set variable in secondary activity conditional on OnClick in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a main activity with four card views. I want each card view, when clicked, to go to a multiple choice quiz specific to that card. In my questions activity, I need to identify which of the card views was clicked in order to determine which set of questions should be called. I tried using boolean values in my main activity but am not able to reference them in my questions activity.

Main Activity

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        c1.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuestionsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("boolean_a", true);
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        c2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuestionsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("boolean_b", true);
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        c3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuestionsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("boolean_c", true);
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        c4.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, QuestionsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("boolean_d", true);
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

The `intent.putExtra("booleanA", true)` in my main activity and `if boolean` statement and `var booleanA = getIntent().getExtras()!!.getBoolean("booleanA")` declaration in my secondary activity crash the app. If I remove `intent.putExtra("booleanA", true)` and `var booleanA = getIntent().getExtras()!!.getBoolean("booleanA")`and remove the if statement, leaving just `mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()`, the app no longer crashes

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_questions.*

class QuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var mCurrentPosition:Int = 1
    private var mQuestionsList:ArrayList<Questions>? = null
    private var mSelectedOptionPosition:Int = 0
    private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0
    var booleanA = getIntent().getExtras()!!.getBoolean("booleanA")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions)
        if (booleanA){
            mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()
        }
        setQuestion()
        radio_button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button2.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button3.setOnClickListener(this)
        radio_button4.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

Comment: are you using **intent.putExtra("boolean_d", true);**  then it should work if you get it in secondry activity like this  **Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");**

Comment: This crashes the app. I've edited my original question to reflect this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should do like this

```
class QuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private var mCurrentPosition:Int = 1
private var mQuestionsList:ArrayList<Questions>? = null
private var mSelectedOptionPosition:Int = 0
private var mCorrectAnswers: Int = 0

//don't get the intent data here
var booleanA: Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions)

    //get the intent data here
    booleanA = getIntent().getExtras()!!.getBoolean("booleanA")

    if (booleanA){
        mQuestionsList = Constants.getQuestions()
    }
    setQuestion()
    radio_button1.setOnClickListener(this)
    radio_button2.setOnClickListener(this)
    radio_button3.setOnClickListener(this)
    radio_button4.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```